# How can I can concatenate multiple array columns in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

In a Hive table, let's assume I have data looking as follows:

    `+----+-----------+-----------+
    | id | some_ids1 | some_ids2 |
    +----+-----------+-----------+
    | 1  | [2, 3]    | [4, 5, 6] |
    | 2  | [7]       | [8, 9]    |
    +----+-----------+-----------+`

and I would like to obtain something like:

    `+----+------------------+
    | id | concatenated_ids |
    +----+------------------+
    | 1  | [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  |
    | 2  | [7, 8, 9]        |
    +----+------------------+`

In my actual example, the inner types are not primitives, so casting to string doesn't work. How are array columns concatenated in Hive?

Comment: Try to use concat_ws(',',some_ids1 ,some_ids2 ) from table . This will concatenate your array and string. But the final  value will  be a string value

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic UDF pass these two columns and concatenate it and return as an array.

```
public class ArraySum extends UDF {
  public List<Double> evaluate(List<Double> list1, List<Double> list2) {
    return list1.addAll(list2)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!